# Beaumont - Pierce Principal theorem

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

In book *R. Göbel, P. Hill, Wolfgang "Abelian Group Theory and Related Topics"*, I found next Beaumont -Pierce Principal theorem: Any torsion-free ring $R$ of finite rank is quasi-equal to $S\oplus N$, where $N$ is nilradical, and $S$ is subring of $R$.

My question is: is $R$ need to be commutative in this theorem. If "No", what nilradical mean for noncimmutative rings?

Answer (score 1):

No, every endomorphism ring of a torsion-free group falls into this class of rings and they are usually non-commutative.